# Adobe's Comb of property is not functioning when Javascript added PDF is integrated in the code

Tags: javascript, .net, adobe, aspose, form-fields

I have eight boxes in a field similar to the one above. Each digit should go in its own box if my input value is less than or equal to 8. I am using a comb of property to accomplish that.

[image]

Say If my input value is greater than 8 then the entire value should be adjusted in the given 8 boxes. But when I use comb of then value greater than 8 is getting trimmed off from the field.

Therefore, I utilized Javascript to accomplish the above scenario. Using Javascript, I was able to find the solution. It functions flawlessly in Adobe Reader. However, my code did not function when I uploaded the identical PDF in it.

I am using the `aspose` library for filling out the fields. Could you please help me with the above scenario?

Comment: Looks like you have also created similar topic in Aspose.PDF support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-library-is-not-able-to-detect-the-javascript-in-the-pdf/275919/2). We have responded you there and you can please follow up.